# Handling dynamic text inputs with one onChange handler and no name properties in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble keeping track of multiple onChange events without a name property pre defined. As of right now one text input will control all inputs. I've seen several examples with static inputs or one input working, but nothing with multiple dynamic inputs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { updateCartItem, removeCartItem } from '../shared/actions'

class CheckoutContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        value: ''
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target
        const value = target.value
        this.setState({ value: value })
    }

    render() {
        const cartItems = this.props.cartItems
        const { value } = this.state
        return (
                <div className='checkout-container'>
                    {cartItems && cartItems.map((cart, i) =>
                        <div key={i} className='checkout-item'>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                maxLength='2'
                                placeholder={cart.itemUnits}
                                value={value}
                                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    cartItems: state.cartReducer.cartItems
})

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(CheckoutContainer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your data structure, you can give your inputs a name.

```
class CheckoutContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {};

  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="checkout-container">
        {cartItems &&
          cartItems.map((cart, i) => (
            <div key={i} className="checkout-item">
              <label>{cart.item}</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                maxLength="2"
                name={cart.item}
                placeholder={cart.itemUnits}
                value={value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This one liner state = {}; solved everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass additional values to your `handleChange` from `onChange` handler

```
class CheckoutContainer extends Component {
    state = {
        value: ''
    }

    handleChange = (event, cart) => {
         // here you have access to cart
        this.setState({ [cart.name]: event.target.value })
    }

    render() {
        const cartItems = this.props.cartItems
        const { value } = this.state
        return (
                <div className='checkout-container'>
                    {cartItems && cartItems.map((cart, i) =>
                        <div key={i} className='checkout-item'>
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                maxLength='2'
                                placeholder={cart.itemUnits}
                                value={value}
                                onChange={(event)=> this.handleChange(event, cart)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
        )
    }
}
```